# Jquery Mobile & PhoneGap - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 on my computer.  I am interested in creating and learning to create a mobile app.  I have been on the internet for the past several hours, researching tutorials for doing this with Dreamweaver, and I have found how to do it.

My issue is that all of the two dozen documents I found said I needed **jquery mobile** and **PhoneGap**.  I have successfully downloaded the lasted "versions" of these utilities on my computer and unzipped them to my desktop.  For the last 3 and 1/2 hours I have been attempting to figure out how to "install" these files so that the toolbars/options appear in Dreamweaver.  Every single document I have found says that I can find the "sample" by going to:
New - Page From Sample and that the 3 mobile options or "templates" would be there.

I am running a Windows 7 PC with Adobe Dreamweaver 5.5.  I would appreciate any help or assistance to installing, implementing or whatever the term is; PhoneGap and Jquery.

-Greg

Comment: Seems like you are using very old documentations that are relevant to PhoneGap (The Dreamweaver version doesn't matter). PhoneGap is now installed via a command line interface, through NodeJS. You should follow install instructions from the authors for most up to day methods: http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: Use android ADT for developing for android application. Create project using CLI as mention on phonegap documentation. Make sure you have installed ant nodejs npm etc which require to do CLI project creation

Comment: Thank you for the response, I just saw this now.  I did not receive a notification when this was posted.